# Перенос алгоритма из C в Java

Tags: java, c

Имеется алгоритм расчета CRC-функции, написанный на C. Необходимо добавить данную функцию в приложение, написанное на Java. Проблема в том, что в алгоритме на C повсеместно используется unsigned int, а в Java int всегда знаковый. Из за этого копипастой (само собой с адаптацией к синтаксису Java) перенести код не получается. Бегло погуглив нашел альтернативу в виде JNI, но это "костыль прикрученный к велосипеду", да и хотелось бы реализовать именно на Java. Подскажите, каким образом осуществить перенос без изменения изначальной логики?

```
// Include Files 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
// Preprocessor Constants 
#define byte char 
#define word_32 unsigned long int
#define BUFSIZE 1024 // Size of file buffer in bytes 
#define G 0x04C11DB7 // The generator G 
#define Init 0xFFFFFFFF // Initialization value for CRC_value 
#define TABLEN 256 // Length of look-up table 
#define XorOut 0xFFFFFFFF // To be XORed to final CRC_value 
// Global (file scope) Variables 
static byte Buffer[BUFSIZE]; // The file buffer 
static word_32 CRC_value; // Holds the running CRC value 
static FILE* fp; // File pointer 
static size_t nb; // Number of bytes read from file 
static word_32 table[TABLEN]; // Look-up Table 
// Function Prototypes to Resolve Forward Referencing (See below) 
static void CRCBuffer (int); 
static void InitTable (void); 

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) // argv[1] is FILENAME 
{ 
    // The operator must supply a FILENAME 
    if (argc != 2) { 
        printf("Error: Command line must contain a FILENAME\n"); 
    } 
    // We must be able to open that file 
    else if ((fp=fopen(argv[1],"rb"))== NULL) { 
        printf("Error: Can't open input file\n"); 
    } 
    // Otherwise compute CRC 
    else {
        // Initialize the look-up table 
        InitTable(); 
        // Initialize the CRC value 
        CRC_value = Init; 
        // Loop for each BUFSIZE (or less) block of bytes in FILENAME 
        while (!feof(fp)) { 
            // Attempt to read a block of BUFSIZE bytes 
            nb=fread(Buffer,sizeof(char),BUFSIZE,fp); 
            // If any bytes were read, compute the running CRC_value 
            // for them 
            if (nb>0) { 
                CRCBuffer(nb); 
            } 
        } 
        // Apply XorOut

        CRC_value ^= XorOut; 
        // Close FILENAME 
        fclose(fp); 
        // Report 
        printf("CRC = %08X\n",CRC_value); 
    } 
} 

static void InitTable(void) 
{ 
    word_32 generator = G; // CRC generator 
    word_32 shift_reg; // A shift register 
    word_32 leading_bit; // MSB of shift_reg before shift 
    int i; // Index into table 0..TABLEN 
    int k; // Bit index into byte 7..0 
    for (i=0; i<TABLEN; i++) { 
        shift_reg = ((word_32)i << 24); 
        for (k=7; k>=0; k--) { 
            leading_bit = shift_reg & 0x80000000; 
            shift_reg = shift_reg << 1; 
            if (leading_bit) { 
                shift_reg = shift_reg ^ generator; 
            } 
        } 
            table[i] = shift_reg; 
    } 
}

static void CRCBuffer(int nb) 
{ 
    int i; // Byte index into buffer 
    int k; // Index into look-up table 
    // Loop for each byte in Buffer 
    for (i=0; i<nb; i++) { 
        // Compute index into look-up table for the current byte 
        k = ( (CRC_value>>24) ^ (int)Buffer[i] ) & 0xFF; 
        // Update the running CRC_value for the curtrent byte 
        CRC_value = (CRC_value << 8) ^ table[k]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: А может вам готовая реализация подойдет? Например https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов В доках не указаны вх. параметры (тот же полином), а по результатам проверки получается другое значение. Мне же необходимы такие же значения.

Comment: А вы укажите для строки байт 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35 (то есть "12345") какой результат должен быть. Ваш 0x04C11DB7 - стандартный CRC32, что наводит меня на мысль о неправильном использовании Java-реализации.

Comment: Создать файл с нужными байтами - не проблема, к слову. Пока я склоняюсь к выводу что и сишный код, и существующая реализация в Java одинаковы, только вы неверно используете ее в Java.

Comment: Если используются логический операции, то проблем вроде не должно быть. Только вместо `>>` (арифметический сдвиг с сохранением знака) надо применять `>>>` (настоящий логический сдвиг)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Похоже, вы правы. Проблема с типами скорее всего. Если не затруднит, не могли бы Вы привести пример кода для Java для сравнения?

Comment: @I.Perevoz не мог бы, я не жавист ни разу. Но я могу четко сказать на каком наборе байт (небольшой длины) какой алгоритм CRC32 что должен дать. И иногда по результату и входным данным сам алгоритм.

Comment: Есть подозрения, что реализации отличаются возвратом: в одном случае результат ксорится с  0xFFFFFFFF, в другом - нет. **UPD** проверил, так и есть. java.util.zip.CRC32, в отличие от вашей сишной реализации, возвращает результат `^0xFFFFFFFF`. С учётом этого всё работает точно так же.

Comment: Просто возьмите исходники и сравните http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/zip/CRC32-source.html

Comment: @PinkTux т.е., достаточно будет результат XOR 0xFFFFFFFF ?

Comment: @I.Perevoz, так проверить-то - дело пары секунд... Либо в сишном xor убрать, либо к жавовскому результату добавить, либо как-то ещё :)

Comment: java return (long)crc & 0xffffffffL;

Comment: @Sergey не пойму суть умножения на 0xffffffffL. 32 битный crc, кастуется в 64 бит лонг путем добавления 32 нулей слева. умножается на 32 нуля и 32 единицы. Т.е. по идее ничего не меняется? Или пора идти учить матчасть?

Comment: Наверно при переводе отрицательного Int (тип crc int) в long сохраняется знак, из-за чего старшие 32 бита из 64-х будут заполнены единицами. & ffffffffL для обнуления этих битов.

Answer (score 4):

Вот Вам пример

```
CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("path/to/file.ext"), StandardOpenOption.READ);
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
for (int i = 0; i < mbb.limit(); i++) 
    crc32.update(mbb.get(i)); // байт за байтом скармливаем crc32
fc.close();
// когда всё сожрал, можно посмотреть как он их переварил
long checksum = crc32.getValue(); 
System.out.println(checksum);
```